# Is there any change in angle of sunlight which is entering a hot glass room?

Tags: optics

I am making a glass room which is exposed to sun. The thickness of glass is about 5mm. The inside temperature is about 70 degC higher than the outside temperature. Would there be any change in direction of sun light when it enters the room? If so I am looking for the governing relations of such phenomena

Comment: Are you asking about refraction due to the difference in air density?

Comment: Dang, that is one hot room.

Answer (score 1):

To a first approximation, no. This, of course, assumes that your glass panes are of uniform thickness, but this seems a reasonable assumption.

At a finer scale, the answer is, maybe. If the glass room is sealed, and in the absence of sunlight its temperature and pressure match that of the outdoors, the answer is still no. The index of refraction of a gas such as air is directly proportional to pressure and inversely proportional to temperature, and since for a closed system (fixed volume) pressure varies proportionately with temperature, the two cancel. However, if the room is vented to the outside the temperature will rise and pressure will not. So the index of refraction on the inside will be lower than the outside, and there will be a net change in angle. The effect will be miniscule, however, and completely invisible to the naked eye.

Comment: Thanks indeed for your quick reply. May you refer any book or paper where i can find a relation for the index of refraction as a function of pressure and temperature?